# Why is this a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Why is [Import JavaScript without risk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35209657/939213) marked as a duplicate?

I'm not saying it isn't. I just don't understand why (As I explained in the edit).

**EDIT**

OK. `That solved my problem!` - accepting that this is a duplicate. (Oh, the irony...)

Comment: It's not _closed_ as a duplicate. Someone just flagged it as such, _suggesting_ that it _might_ be duplicate. The banner that you see is visible only to you, until 5 users (or one gold tag badge user) votes it as a duplicate. It looks like you've edited to address why your question isn't duplicate, which is what you're supposed to do.

Comment: @Kendra Yes. You're right. But it does have 2 close votes, and got more downvotes even after my edit.

Comment: Granted, you have some meta commentary in your edit- I would remove the quote and the "Seriously?" and reword the last sentence along the lines of "I've looked at {question} and don't feel it answers my question because {reason you already put}." How you currently have it phrased could potentially cause people to downvote on sight. (Not saying they have, just that it could happen.)

Comment: I actually just wrote a comment about the edit and downvotes. As for close votes, it could be they don't agree with your analysis, or they didn't see your edit when they voted. Only time will tell if it gets closed or not, and if it does it can always be reopened.

Comment: @Kendra Good point! Thanks. I just edited my edit there.

Comment: @gnat Just mentioning I appreciate the irony. :)

Comment: Just delete it.  It's off topic (too broad), and you're just gathering downvotes.  Avoiding JS exploits is a subject better tackled in a book, not in the space allotted for an answer on SO.